# Using ViewSwitcher in childs of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I can't alternate correctly 2 views (from my ViewSwitcher)  in any child of my ExpandableListView. The child that alternate the layout is always the first showed at screen (can be the first child of first group, or third child of 2nd group.. if this child is at first in screen)

This is my code:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
 {
      base.OnCreate(bundle);

      this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main);


      ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.ExpandableListView01);

      loadData();

      MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(this, groups, childs);
      elv.SetAdapter(adapter);



      elv.ChildClick += (object sender, Android.Widget.ExpandableListView.ChildClickEventArgs e) =>
      {
           ViewSwitcher vs = FindViewById<ViewSwitcher>(Resource.Id.details2);
           vs.InAnimation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.fade);
           vs.ShowNext();               

      };
}
```

Moreover, if I change the ChildClick event to next code, the 'fade' animation will be used on the correct child but I will not be using the layout with the ViewSwitcher, so, how can I do it?

```
 elv.ChildClick += (object sender, Android.Widget.ExpandableListView.ChildClickEventArgs e) =>
          {
               Animation animation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.fade);

               e.V.StartAnimation(animation)  ;           

          };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself.

```
elv.ChildClick += (object sender, Android.Widget.ExpandableListView.ChildClickEventArgs e) =>
{

     ViewSwitcher vs = (ViewSwitcher)e.V;
     vs.InAnimation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.fade);

     vs.ShowNext();


};
```